# Java Exposed DropDown Menu only one item

Tags: java, android, drop-down-menu, autocompletetextview, material-components-android

I try to create an Android App with Exposed DropDown Menus like shown here: 
https://material.io/components/menus/android#exposed-dropdown-menus

[image: on some occasion it shows like this][image: expected output]

The left image occurs on the first time opening the menu. Selection of one item, changes to the right situation. Reselecting the same item again, changes back to the left situation.

Here is the implementation of my Adapter:

```
public class FilterMenuCategoryAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private static final String TAG = "FilterMenuCategoryAdapter";
    List<String> categoryList;
    LvElCategoryBinding binding;
    Context context;

    public FilterMenuCategoryAdapter(Context context) {
        super(context, 0, getCompleteCategoryList());
        this.context = context;
        this.categoryList = getCompleteCategoryList();
    }

    public FilterMenuCategoryAdapter(Context context, List<String> categoryList) {
        super(context, 0, categoryList);
        this.context = context;
        this.categoryList = new ArrayList<>(categoryList);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return categoryList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public String getItem(int position) {
        return categoryList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()), R.layout.lv_el_category, parent, false);
        }
        String category = categoryList.get(position);
        binding.tvTitle.setText(category);
        binding.icon.setImageResource(new IconNameMapper().get(category));
        return binding.getRoot();
    }

}
```

This is the used XML:

```
 <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    style="@style/dropDownMenuOnWhite"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp">

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/filterMenu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:inputType="none"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:text="@string/show_all"
        android:textAlignment="textEnd"
        android:textColor="@color/primaryTextColor"
        android:textSize="@dimen/font_size" />
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

And in my Fragment Class I call it like this:

```
FilterMenuCategoryAdapter adapter = new FilterMenuCategoryAdapter(this.getContext());
binding.filterMenu.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Currently, every selection in the menu breaks my `onClick` events. So I'm very happy about any help!

Comment: Is `binding.filterMenu` the `AutoCompleteTextView`? I see it `filterCategory` in layout

Comment: yes they are the same. The error is just in the post here. Corrected it

Comment: something has to be wrong in my Adapter implementation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn't in the `dataBinding` itself; but the way it's implemented.

When you hit the menu for the first time, it's shown correctly because the `converView` is `null` and the condition is met to build up the binding object.

The cause that the menu items disappear when items are clicked; that when the `getView()` is called again, it has a new `convertView` object which has a new state that is different than the old call of `getView()`; but you ignored it, and used the old `binding` object with its original state for finding views; and this makes dataBinding unable to inflate the views of the new state (maybe it refers to the views of the old recycling).

That is why the `convertView` is passed as a method parameter; so that you need to use the brand new `convertView` every time views are recycled.

To fix this; you need to do the same by saving view of the dataBinding; which returned by `binding.getRoot()`. And you must use the `convertView` to save this dataBinding view state on. This is typically can be done with a `ViewHolder` and saving the view & its state with `setTag()`:

The ViewHolder has a similar idea as `RecyclerView` view holder:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ItemViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        LvElCategoryBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()), R.layout.lv_el_category, parent, false);
        holder = new ItemViewHolder(binding);
        holder.view = binding.getRoot();
        holder.view.setTag(holder); 
    } else {
        holder = (ItemViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    String category = categoryList.get(position);
    holder.binding.tvTitle.setText(category);
    holder.binding.icon.setImageResource(new IconNameMapper().get(category));
    return holder.view;
}

private static class ItemViewHolder {
    private View view;
    private LvElCategoryBinding binding;

    ItemViewHolder(LvElCategoryBinding binding) {
        this.view = binding.getRoot();
        this.binding = binding;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:
I fixed it! Using DataBinding in getView() killed it every time for me. 
Following solution worked:

```
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                    R.layout.lv_el_category, parent, false
            );
        }
        TextView title = convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_title);
        ShapeableImageView image = convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        String category = categoryList.get(position);
        title.setText(category);
        image.setImageResource(new IconNameMapper().get(category));
        return convertView;
    }
```

If you know, how to use DataBinding in getView() please let me know!